# iPhone Data Best Practices - caching vs remote

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, caching

I'm developing an iPhone app that uses a user account and a web API to get results (json) from a website. The results are a list of user's events. 
Just looking for some advice or strategies - when to cache and when to make an api call... and if the iPhone SDK has anything built in to handle these scenarios.

When I get the results from the server, they populate an array in a controller. In the UI, you can go from a table listing view, to a view of an individual event result - so two controllers share a reference to the same event object.
What gets tricky is that a user can change the details of an event. In this case I make a copy of the local Event object for the user's changes, in case they make an error. If the api call successfully goes through and updates that event on the server, I take these local changes from the Event copy and set the original Event object to match with setters.
I have the original controller observing if any change is made to the local Event object so that it can reflect it in the UI.
Is this the right way of doing things? I don't want to make too many API calls to reload data from the server, But after a user makes an update should I be pulling down the list again with the API call?
...I want to be careful that my local objects don't become out of sync with the remote.
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I took a similar approach with an app I built.  I simply made a duplicate version of the remote data model with Core Data, and I use etags on the backend to prevent sync issues (in my case, it's okay to create duplicate records).

It sounds like you're taking a good approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

Some time back, I developed an iOS app where in, I had almost same requirement to store data on server as well as locally to avoid several network call and also user can see their information without any delay.

In that app, user can store photos, nodes, checkIns and social media post and with all this data, app can form a beautiful timeline. So what we did was, we had everything locally and whenever user phone come in some **WIFI** zone, we start uploading that data to server and sync both (local and remote) databases.

Note this method works well when only one user can access this data.